# Set background image for iPod, iPhone, and iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to override different background imagery to run on my application. I used the code from this question; [set background images for Iphone 3g, Iphone 4s and Iphone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939181/set-background-images-for-iphone-3g-iphone-4s-and-iphone-5)

Thankfully the code is simple. I also set these in the .m file just in case.

.h

```
@property (retain strong) UIImage* Image 

@property (retain, strong) UIImageView.
```

.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

//SYNTHESIZE JUST IN CASE

@synthesize backgroundImageView=backgroundImageView;
@synthesize Image=Image;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

//SETS A UIIMAGEVIEW TO BE SET TO A CUSTOM UIIMAGE (JPG)

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Image];
[backgroundImageView setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:backgroundImageView];

//I EXCPECTED THIS NEXT LINE OF CODE TO WORK TO SET A SEPARATE BACKGROUND FOR IPAD...

UIImage *Image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11@2x.jpg"];
}
else

//THIS ELSE STATEMENT IS THE IMAGE THAT ACTUALLY RASTERIZES FOR BOTH IPAD AND IPOD TEST DEVICES

{
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7@2x.jpg"];
}

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:Image];


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The override isn't working quite as expected. Only the else statement runs no matter what image i set in the if statement.

My question; are the dimensions (568) in the if statement correct to rasterize a separate image for iPad devices? If not please let me know, thanks.

Additional info: deployment target: 6.1
Additional info: i received an error at run time (even though it still ran) akin to something about a discrepancy between my nib file and story board. I am not using a nib though. 
?

Comment: 568 is the height of an iPhone 5.  768 is the height of an iPad

Comment: Also you declare properties for your background view and image, but then use local variables rather than the properties.  Additionally your `Image` property (which should be `image` - classes start with upper case, variables start with lower case) will be retained by the background view so you only need a weak property, not strong

Comment: 768? Thank you I will try it ( I am using an iPad mini)

Comment: I will try a weak property also thx recompiling in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the correct values:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
    // iPhone, iPod Touch
}

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    // iPhone 5
}

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 750) {
    // iPhone 6
}

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024) {
    // iPad
}

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1242) {
    // iPhone 6 Plus
}
```

1. iPhone `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}`
2. iPhone 5 `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}`
3. iPhone 6 `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] {{0, 0}, {750, 1334}}`
4. iPad `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}`
5. iPhone 6 Plus `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] {{0, 0}, {1242, 2208}}`

**Edit**: *Added iPhone 6 and 6 Plus to maintain this list as per [Jules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450456/jules)' comment, but do not recommend using this method to differentiate between phones or even pick the right image.*

---

**Proper Approach**

Use an assets catalog.

Comment: What about iphone 6 etc ?

Comment: @Jules: you make an excellent point. This solution is not scalable. I was purely responding to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602007/, but you do no want to go down that road.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect yeah thanks, I have my own question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948931/xcode-7-asset-catalog-universal-device-background-image-support asset catalog doesn't currently seem able to do this ?